# Jquery/php/taconite radio buttons

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button, taconite

I am new to Jquery and taconite

I want to have a page that does the following
It has multiple panels
the first contains search criteria to submit a request to a mysql database
The second panel contains the results of the search
I would like to use radio buttons on the second panel to get more specific details from the data base and display them in a third panel.

I have got the second panel being populated as I want (using taconite etc)

The "front-end" php file creates the page with the required panels and the second panel is populated using teconite contentsReplace

I have a radio button function in the "front end" program but it doesn't work. I want it to query mysql and populate the third panel

Finally the second panel contains three tabs which are populated by the search.

All working as expected except the radio buttons.

any suggestions ???

PS Originally I used php/mysql to display all of the information from the records but the final page was unattractively large.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need ajax-requests for do such things. the answer of haroldo is correct. taconite is useful for full-dynamic webpages.

if you create a search engine and you want get the results live without page-refresh, you can use taconite. if you want to change many parts of the page by one ajax-request, you can also use taconite. but when there are fix elements with static function: why a request? any request is traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with tactonite, but as far as the jquery goes there should be a an easy solution where the tabs id is the same as the radio's values:

```
  $('.radios_class').click( function(){show_tab();})


 function show_tab(){
    var desired_tab = '#'+$(this).attr('value');
    $('.tab_class').hide();
    $(desired_tab).show();
    }
```